# Get css content to have the same width as parent div

Tags: html, css

I'm modifying css on a website where I cannot change the html markup.
I'm trying to have a "tooltip" like box to display after a certain content, but:

1 - I don't want the below contents to shift, but to be covered so I'm using position:absolute

2 - Here's where I'm stuck. I'm trying to have the "tooltip" to have the same width as the div (the #main red div in this example), without having to set an amount of pixels / pixels per screen size.

Is there a way to do this?

```css
#main {
  height:50px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:red;
  display:inline-block;
  /*needs to be inline-block*/
}
#secondary {
  height:50px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:yellow;
  display:inline-block;
}
#main:hover::after {
  content:"tips displayed";
  background-color:blue;
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">content</div>
<div id="secondary">content</div>
```

Comment: If you remove absolute, the width will work. Even if you follow @bron ans,  will work.

Comment: Changed answer in 2 inline-block div's. (main & secondary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `left: 0; right: 0;` for the ::after element. Note the `position: relative` in the #main and #secondary element to be sure it works fine in the flow of your html structure.

```css
#main {
  height:50px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:red;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
#secondary {
  height:50px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:yellow;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
#main:hover::after,
#secondary:hover::after {
  content:"tips displayed";
  background-color:blue;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">content</div>
<div id="secondary">content</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The #main div needs to be inline-block unfortunately. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the width of the child as inherit.
Width: inherit;

Comment: This is a simple property value I had never used. It works great for the example, but unfortunately not for my actual code for some reason. Perhaps something needs to be specified to force this to work.